# Scheme - prevent program from crashing when dividing by 0

Tags: scheme, racket, zero, divide

My program interrupts functions from a file, like

```
   (   10          (print "+1/+0    = " (/ (+ 1) (+ 0))))
   (   11          (print "-1/+0    = " (/ (- 1) (+ 0))))
```

except my program crashes with

```
/: division by zero
     context...:
```

I know i could add 0.0 to the 0s, but is there another way that may be simpler?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will produce something like inf or nan for floats 
> (/ 1 0.0)
+inf.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could handle the error and display a message…

```
(with-handlers ([exn:fail? (lambda (exn)
                             (printf "+1/+0    = +inf.0"))])
  (printf "+1/+0    = ~s" (/ (+ 1) (+ 0))))
```

…Or you could convert every number to make sure that floating-point division is used:

```
(printf "+1/+0    = ~s"
        (/ (exact->inexact (+ 1)) (exact->inexact (+ 0))))
```

But why bother? if you *know* that there's an integer division by zero and that it *will* crash your program, then make sure that floating-point division is used directly in the input file:

```
(printf "+1/+0    = ~s" (/ (+ 1.0) (+ 0.0)))
```

Any of the above options will print the same result:

```
+1/+0    = +inf.0
```

Comment: yeah, but it doesnt crash my program when i use 0.0, like ive tested that and i know that works, but i dont know how to read in an integer (0) from the file and add 0.0 before it's evaluated. it's like a weird case. i feel there's an easier way to do it then potentially scan every line looking for zeroes

Comment: @ghostofrasputin See my updated answer, I added yet another alternative: convert all numbers using `exact->inexact`